# Selective lining figures with KPFonts

Tags: oldstylenums, kpfonts

I'm writing a document that uses OSF with KPFonts. However, they look a bit awkward within tables. Is there a way of switching to lining figures locally with KPFonts?

Comment: Use math mode for the numbers.

Comment: @egreg The problem is that it gives my CM figures, rather than lining KPFont figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using math mode for numeric columns should work; however, if you really want that *all* tabular environments use lining figures, you can do a trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
Numbers: 1234; numbers in math: $1234$

A tabular, first column text, second column math

\begin{tabular}{l>{$}l<{$}}
123 & 123 \\
456 & 456
\end{tabular}

\preto\tabular{\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont}

A tabular, first column text, second column math

\begin{tabular}{l>{$}l<{$}}
123 & 123 \\
456 & 456
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, in the second table both columns are equal. If you prefer not having to choose math mode (which might be a nuisance), add the line

```
\preto\tabular{\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont}
```

to your preamble. Remember to `\usepackage{etoolbox}`.

Comment: Thanks. What's the use of having `etoolbox` here?

Comment: Oh, OK, I just didn't know about the `\preto` command!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why this works (i.e. why it doesn't mess my smallcaps etc. up):

```
\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont
```